# Qual a diferença ente getRating() e getProgress()?

Tags: android, tipagem, método

Segundo a documentação o getProgress retorna o level de progresso do rating bar, enquanto que o getRating retorno a quantidade de estrelas do rating bar.

**Então em termos gerais o getProgress retorna um valor double enquanto que o getRating retorna um valor inteiro?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

É o contrário:

O [`getProgress()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#getProgress()) retorna um valor inteiro, enquanto o [`getRating()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#getRating()) retorna um `float`.

**A diferença**

Apesar de o `RatingBar` ser uma subclasse do `ProgressBar` o `getProgress` geralmente é usado para recuperar a porcentagem (int) de um ProgressBar, enquanto `getRating` é usado para recuperar a qualificação de estrelas atual (float) de um RatingBar.

Answer (score 4):

[getProgress()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#getProgress()) deve ser usando quando usa um ProgressBar e [getRating()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#getRating()) quando usa um [RatingBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar).
O mesmo se aplica a `setProgress()` e `setRating()`.

**TL;DR**

[getProgress()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar.html#getProgress()) é um método da classe [ProgressBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ProgressBar) da qual [RatingBar](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar) deriva(*extends*) indirectamente através de AbsSeekBar.

O propósito do ProgressBar é indicar visualmente a "quantidade" parcial, a que já decorreu, de um qualquer processamento.
É usada uma representação visual cuja dimensão é proporcional à "quantidade" decorrida.
Essa dimensão é calculada relacionando o valor mínimo e máximo do valor e a dimensão mínima e máxima do ProgressBar.
Por padrão esses valores são 0 e 100, podendo ser alteradas através dos métodos `setMin()` e  `setMax()`.
O valor da "quantidade" decorrida do processo é atribuída por `setProgress()` e obtida por `getProgress()` que, ao contrário do que diz, retorna int.
O uso dos valores 0 e 100 proporciona que a "quantidade" decorrida seja indicada como uma percentagem.

Por outro lado, o RatingBar é usado para representar uma classificação, usando estrelas.
O número de estrelas a mostrar pelo RatingBar é atribuído por `setNumStars()`.
Em vez de um int, que é usado para indicar o *progress*, é usado um float para indicar o *ranting*.
O uso de um float, em conjunto com a indicação de um *step*, permite que o *ranting* seja representado pelo preenchimento parcial da estrela.
Assim, ao contrario do que diz, o método [getRating()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RatingBar.html#getRating()) retorna float.
Note que o valor retornado por `getRating()` pode não ser igual ao número de estrelas preenchidas. Esse número depende do valor máximo para o *rating*, do *step* e do número de estrelas do RatingBar.
Apesar dos métodos `setProgress()`, `getProgress()` e `setMin()` estarem disponíveis não devem ser utilizados quando se usa o RatingBar.

Este é um bom exemplo de um caso em que não deveria ter sido utilizada herança.

Comment: "Este é um bom exemplo de um caso em que não deveria ter sido utilizada herança." Disse tudo!